# Reading @Path from properties file

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

The rest application in build using spring and jersy.
I need a rest application that can read the value of @path annotation from the properties file.
PFB the code sample:-

```
@Controller
@Path("report")
public  class CommonService extends BaseService
{

    @Path("specificGet")
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getReport ()
    {
    -----------
    -----------
     }
```

I want the value that is now "specificGet" to be readable from a .properties file.
For example if i have the below entry in properties file:-

```
path.getwithoutparam=thispathforGet
```

I want to refer to this property for @path annotation
Please comments/suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Does `@Path("${path.getwithoutparam}")` work? I know this works in Spring MVC, but I'm not sure about Spring with Jersey integration

Comment: Oh i'm to slow, but i had the same idea. Be sure to put path.getwithoutparam in a resource bundle in order to allow spring to find it

Comment: @ geoand    Is does not work. The value for @Path is taken as "${path.getwithoutparam}" as it is. Not the value from properties file

Comment: I can't believe I haven't met this situation before

Comment: Can you use regex in a `@Path` like you can in `@RequestMapping`?  If so, you could use regex to pull in all characters, then compare the matched part in your handler and either throw a 404 or let them by.

Answer (score 0):

I might get some downvotes :)) but I'm pretty sure there is no out-of-the-box support for property placeholders for @Path annotations.

I guess you would have to build your own annotation processor in this case, that plugs into Spring property handling system.

Comment: I can't do what i wanted to do :( :(

I was asking the javac compiler to execute arbitrary code to read a properties file from disk, extract a value, and insert that as a constant into my code (at compile time).

The value for the annotation must be available at compile time.And if i am trying to sullpy the value from properties file, it will not happen. As properties file is read at runtime.

Comment: Need to figure out a differnt kind of logic....Thanks a lot for the quick response